Number of $m\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices such that no two $1$'s are adjacent.
How many $m\times n$ $(0,1)$-matrices are there such that no two $1$'s are adjacent in either rows columns (diagonals are not considered adjacent)? I tried solving the simpler, $1\times n$ version, and got the recurrence $t_n = t_{n-1} + t_{n-2}$, $n\ge3$, with $t_1 = 2, t_2 = 3$. I have no idea how to generalize this to $m\times n$.

By adjacent do you just mean directly above, below, and on either side, or are diagonals considered adjacent too?

$t_{2,n} = t_{2,n-1} + 2 \sum_{i=2}^n t_{2,n-i}$ for $n>1$, where $t_{2,1}=3$ and (formally) $t_{2,0}=1$.

Note that when $n=1$ these are Fibonacci numbers.

@Pranay I don't think your recurrence is correct, by bruteforcing, i found that $t_{2,2} = 7$, whereas by your recurrence, $t_{2,2} = t_{2,1} + 2t_{2,0} = 5$.

@Waffle. You are right! I should have written $t_{2,n} = t_{2,n-1}+2(t_{2,n-2}+\cdots +t_{2,-1})$ for $n\ge1$, where formally $t_{2,0}=t_{2,-1}=1$.
